# How to predict intuitively the recurrence relations of josephus problem?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, computability

i have studied the **Josephus problem** from the concrete mathematics book.I have understand all related calculations discussed on that book.However i have some difficulties regarding to  recurrence relations of Josephus problem.

`J(1) = 1 ;
J(2n) = 2J(n) − 1 , for Even number
J(2n + 1) = 2J(n) + 1 , for Odd number`

I did several trials with many sample numbers(both even & odd) and this 2 recurrence relations holds perfect every time.I also understand it closed forms.
But however, my mind gets lost whenever i try to rediscover these recurrence relations without seeing the solutions.
So my curiosity on knowing:

Why to start with 2n instead of n ? (i got this one now)

**What questions i should ask my self to predict these recurrence relations(J(2n) = 2J(n) − 1 and J(2n + 1) = 2J(n) + 1) intuitively?**

again don't misunderstand me. i already did all calculations and understand maths in behind it.So **no need** to demonstrate any even odd examples.But i am missing the intuitive picture in my mind.Thats why these recurrences became memorization to me.

please reply & enlighten me with your creative explanation. :)

Comment: J(1)=1, J(2)=2J(1)-1=1, (because 2 is a 2n [even] number), J(3)=2J(2)+1=3 (because 3 is a 2n+1 [odd] number, and so on... (Or is this what you did not want to hear? Then I am sorry.)

Comment: you are right its what i don't want to hear.thanks anyway.

Comment: Forgive me then. However you just have an "odd" question: "Why to start with 2n instead of n ?" Who starts with n? There are instructions as to what to do if n is odd and what to do if it is even.

Comment: i understand about 2n things u said.However the second question  is still the main question that i m looking for. thanks.